# Trigger a Function using python- telegram-bot without using the command

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am a beginner and I am working on a telegram bot. I want the function "AP" to be called whenever a message is sent to a telegram group. but right now my code is such that the MessageHandler is triggered whenever the command /AP "followed by the message" is sent to the chat. How can I make it happen?

```
async def AP(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    # function implementation
if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token('1234:ABCDEF9101112').build()
    
    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start) #To tell your bot to listen to /start commands,

    AP_handler = MessageHandler(filters.ALL, AP)#Autosend/AutoPost the messages
    
    application.add_handler(start_handler) 
    application.add_handler(AP_handler)
  
    application.run_polling() # application.run_polling() runs the bot until you hit CTRL+C
```

I tried changing the filters but it hasn't worked to automatically call the function AP. I think because of my lack of knowledge I don't know where to look in order to find the solution of the problem.

Comment: The bot needs to be an admin in the group to receive messages/

Comment: yes I got that but what if I want to receive messages from groups of which I am not the creator? Do you have any solution for that or may you know how I can find it?

Comment: Is the bot member of that group, and admin as well?

Comment: the bot is a member of that group but not the administrator

Comment: Then it's not possible, it needs to be an admin, not necessarily the creator, but it needs access right to see messages. You probably now see something like "has no access to messages" by the bot name in the group member list

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to receive all Messages in a Chat, you either need to add your bot as an Admin, or need to disable privacy mode (https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#privacy-mode).
To disable Privacy mode, got to BotFather (https://t.me/BotFather) in Telegram, send the command /mybots , then choose your bot, choose "Bot Settings", choose "Group Privacy" and disable it there ("Turn off") (if you not already had done it).
Then you need to readd the bot to your group.